# Include parameter in URL after submit form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have search form, now after submit, the site will return view and URL like this `https://localhost:44303/Product/Search`, but i want the URL to include query string `https://localhost:44303/Product/Search?name=abc&brand=edf`  so the visitor can copy and share it

```
-- view --
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Product", FormMethod.Post)
{
  <input id="name" name="name">
  <input id="brand" name="brand">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
}

-- controller --
public ActionResult Search(SearchPara para)
{
   // do stuff and return view + model
}

-- model --
class SearchPara {
  public string name {get; set;}
  public string brand {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: change form method to `FormMethod.Get`, and move the backend search logic to the Get method as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing your Form Method to "GET", your form will submit to the "Search" action of your controller and map to the model.

In your view, this should be the new form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Product", FormMethod.Get)
{
  <input id="name" name="name">
  <input id="brand" name="brand">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
}
```

The form inputs will be part of the search URL (and available to copy).

```
 https://localhost:44303/Product/Search?name=abc&brand=edf
```